# Getting issue in protoc-gen-rbi installation dependency

Tags: go, build, protocol-buffers, protocols, protoc

While doing make build I am getting this error, I tried installing using
`brew install protoc-gen-rbi`
After installing this I get the missing dependency as protoc-gen-ruby_csf and after installing this I am getting the previous error and a cycle continues.

So how to resolve this issue?

I tried installing it but as said I get circular installing dependency issues.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.